# HQL Custom class

Tags: hibernate, hql

Can someone point me what is wrong with this HQL using custom class? custom class is RegionSummary

```
select new com.entity.RegionSummary(
   awb.fxOriginCode,
   awb.productCode,
   region.regionCode,
   region.zoneCode,
   sum(awb.revenue),
   SUM(awb.chargeableWeightKG),
   SUM(awb.chargeableWeightPounds)
)   From com.entity.AWB awb, com.entity.RegionZoneDestination region
where awb.fxDestinationCode = region.destinationCode
  and awb.status <> :strStatus
  and awb.billPeriod=:strBillPeriod
group by awb.fxOriginCode, awb.productCode, region.regionCode,  region.zoneCode
order by awb.fxOriginCode, awb.productCode, region.regionCode,  region.zoneCode
```

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Incorrect query syntax [select new com.entity.RegionSummary(awb.fxOriginCode, awb.productCode, region.regionCode, region.zoneCode, sum(awb.revenue), SUM(awb.chargeableWeightKG), SUM(awb.chargeableWeightPounds))   From com.entity.AWB awb, com.entity.RegionZoneDestination region where awb.fxDestinationCode = region.destinationCode  and awb.status <> :strStatus  and awb.billPeriod=:strBillPeriod group by awb.fxOriginCode, awb.productCode, region.regionCode,  region.zoneCode  order by awb.fxOriginCode, awb.productCode, region.regionCode,  region.zoneCode]
```

Comment: Could you please format your SQL nicely? Please, follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @RrAllanigue Could you please show full stack trace, and related part of your entities: `com.entity.AWB`, `com.entity.RegionZoneDestination`

Comment: Does it work if you omit the `new RegionSummary` part in the HQL?